# Getting a list of list from a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the string below gotten as the output from another process. I need to get only the list of list within the string out that is by eliminating the following  `0.466, 0.161 : 19.032` that are the characters at the end of the string.

The string:

```
route = '''[[(5371.0, 10558.0, {'volume': 8.627265, 'length': 0.17}), (14604.0, 71071.0, {'volume': 15.135287, 'length': 0.28})], [(68127, 68127.0, {'volume': 10.072853, 'length': 0.25}), (5706, 5706.0, {'volume': 27.82635, 'length': 0.25, })], 0.466, 0.161] : 19.032'''
```

My desired output is the list of list below

```
[[(5371.0, 10558.0, {'volume': 8.627265, 'length': 0.17}), (14604.0, 71071.0, {'volume': 15.135287, 'length': 0.28})],  [(68127, 68127.0, {'volume': 10.072853, 'length': 0.25}), (5706, 5706.0, {'volume': 27.82635, 'length': 0.25})]]
```

I tried this:

```
result = []
for r in eval(route.split(":")[0]):
    if type(r) == type([]):
        result.append(r)
print result
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AMAMIFE/Desktop/obi/SO.py", line 419, in <module>
    for l in eval(route.split(":")[0]):
  File "<string>", line 1
    [[(5371.0, 10558.0, {'volume'
                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Can I get some help with what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: The colon at the end is **not** the only colon. Look at what you are asking `eval` to parse! Switch to [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and look into [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit).

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар no, it isn't.

Comment: @nobi hi, y are u saving the total object to a  file or r u recieving that from some where

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар hello, yes I am receiing it from somewhere else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), not `eval` (which is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/3001761)).

Note that there are multiple colons in your string, some of which are valid syntax. You want to split only on the last, so use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) and set `maxsplit` to `1`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> route = "[[(5371.0, 10558.0, {'volume': 8.627265, 'length': 0.17}), (14604.0, 71071.0, {'volume': 15.135287, 'length': 0.28})], [(68127, 68127.0, {'volume': 10.072853, 'length': 0.25}), (5706, 5706.0, {'volume': 27.82635, 'length': 0.25, })], 0.466, 0.161] : 19.032"
>>> literal_eval(route.rsplit(":", 1)[0])
[[(5371.0, 10558.0, {'volume': 8.627265, 'length': 0.17}), (14604.0, 71071.0, {'volume': 15.135287, 'length': 0.28})], [(68127, 68127.0, {'volume': 10.072853, 'length': 0.25}), (5706, 5706.0, {'volume': 27.82635, 'length': 0.25})], 0.466, 0.161]
```

As you don't want the last two items in the list, use a slice to remove them:

```
>>> literal_eval(route.rsplit(":", 1)[0])[:-2]
[[(5371.0, 10558.0, {'volume': 8.627265, 'length': 0.17}), (14604.0, 71071.0, {'volume': 15.135287, 'length': 0.28})], [(68127, 68127.0, {'volume': 10.072853, 'length': 0.25}), (5706, 5706.0, {'volume': 27.82635, 'length': 0.25})]]
```

Comment: @jonsharp please I need these out as well '0.466, 0.161' can you edit your code pleae thanks

Comment: @Nobi seriously? You don't know how to manipulate a list? *Sigh* edited.